# Is there any annotation to warn that subclasses shouldn't hide a static method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I have a class which contains a public static method in Java. Is there any annotation in java to warn the subclasses not to use same method signature(and thereby hide the superclass method). Any other workarounds would also be fine.

Comment: Eclipse (and probably most major IDEs) issue a warning about that. Besides that there are static code analysis tools like [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) which you can incorporate into your build process.

Comment: @litelite you can't override static methods.

Comment: You wrote " ... not to use same method name ..." - do you mean you want to warn not only when a subclass method is hiding the superclass method but also when it _overloads_ it (i.e. different parameters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the superclass method `final`:

```
class Foo {
    public static final void go() {}
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public static void go() {};  // Error
}
```

[**Ideone Example**](http://ideone.com/8WsId2)

Comment: I misunderstood that `final` keyword is not gonna work for static methods. Figured it out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need such annotations because what you a trying to do in not going to compile...

in java you just can not override static method

---

as @thomas suggested(+1 dafuer), you can play with the visibility of the static method
example:

```
public class Calculator {

    static int add(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("a+b= " + (a + b));
        return a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

and then

```
public class ScientificCalculator extends Calculator {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("11111");
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't override them but you can _hide_ them.

Comment: OP wants to get warned about such cases ?

Comment: That's what he wrote: "Is there any annotation in java to warn the subclasses not to use same method name(and thereby _hide the superclass method_)"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such annotation to flag the declaration of the method. You could, however, approach this from the opposite direction. Instead of focusing on the method declaration, you could look at uses of it. The `-Xlint:all` will warn if any uses could be a problem. A static method with an identical signature to a static method in its superclass will only cause problems when that method is referenced from an instance instead of statically. Consider this example:

```
public class Foo {

  public static String getFoo(){
    return "foo";
  }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Bar bar = new Bar();
    String s = bar.getFoo(); // Actually calls Foo.getFoo()
    System.out.println(s); // Prints "foo"

   }
}
```

In the code above, we reference the static `getFoo()` method from `Foo` through an instance of `Bar`. The `bar.getFoo()` line actually calls the static method from `Foo`. Now suppose we add a static method with an identical signature to `Bar`:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
   public static String getFoo(){
      return "bar";
   }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Bar bar = new Bar();
    String s = bar.getFoo(); // Actually calls Bar.getFoo()
    System.out.println(s); // Prints "bar"

   }
}
```

This hides the `Foo.getFoo()` method from `Bar` and now the `Bar.getFoo()` method is invoked instead. In a real context, this would almost certainly break `Bar`. If you compile with the `-Xlint:all` option, then you'd get this message:

`warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, Foo, instead of by an expression`

You'd notice this when you compile the first version of `Bar` and you could fix it to `String s = Foo.getFoo()` right away. Later when `getFoo` is also added to `Bar`, the original code will still work because it explicitly references the method in `Foo`. If you always explicitly call static methods by referencing the class in which they are declared, then the only problem with having an identical method in a subclass is that it's not exactly a best practice. Maybe there is a way to flag the declaration, too, but I'd focus on making sure that the static method is used properly.